# input[type="submit"][disabled] not working for IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am having 3 states for my input submit button.

1. Active : Orange button
2. Mouse down : Dark gray button
3. Disabled : Light gray button

   `<input type="submit" id="savebtn" class="save_button"/>`

CSS:

```
save_button {
  background: url('/Images/save_button_active.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-right: 19px;
  width: 216px;
  border: solid 0px;
  color: #fff!important;
  background-position: 0px -30px;
}

.save_button-active
{
  background:url('/Images/save_button_mousedown.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-right: 19px;
  width: 216px;
  border:solid 0px;
  color:#fff!important; 
  background-position:0px 2px;
  margin-right:20px\0;
}
.save_button[type="submit"]:disabled, .save_button[type="submit"][disabled]
{
 background:url('/Images/save_button_disabled.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 32px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-right: 19px;
 width: 216px;
 border:solid 0px;
 color:#fff!important; 
 background-position:0px 1px;
 margin-right:20px\0;
}
```

This is working well with Chrome and other IE versions except for IE8, the 3rd disabled state is turning to orange and gray text.

I am adding active classes using jquery.

```
fnMouseDownEvents(buttonObj, mousedownClass, mouseupClass);
```

I pass something below:

```
fnMouseDownEvents('save_button', 'save_button-active', 'save_button')
```

I search the stackoverflow for various solution, tried different solution, but in vain.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am using version from IE8 till Edge..!

Comment: some doubts.. you are missing `.` in the very first line of `css` above. Is that typo? By saying `.save_button-active` is it that some active class is added or should it be `.save_button:active`?

Comment: you might also need to paste relevant code for html and js showing us how you are adding it!! Or a js fiddle will be more helpful

Comment: @GuruprasadRao jsfiddle is okay as a supplement to a question, but any code necessary for understanding the question must be in the question itself. We can't have half of the JavaScript tag disappearing if jsfiddle ever folds.

Comment: `.save_button[type="submit"][disabled]` is not a valid selector, thus the whole rule set should fail. `.save_button[type="submit"]:disabled` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I simply the function. Is that what you want?

```
$(".save_button").mouseup(function() {
   $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Check this at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ddqogya/).